# When you accelerate, does your field of vision increase?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, speed-of-light

When you accelerate, does your field of vision increase? I think it does, because you would be catching up with light that travels (almost) perpendicular to your direction. However, I would like to know whether length contraction and time dilation play a role.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/275921/what-do-the-stars-really-look-like-if-you-could-travel-at-almost-lightspeed/275943#275943

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes or no depending on how you interpret the question.

First:  The act of accelerating can't change what you're actually seeing, because what you're actually seeing depends entirely on the photons that are reaching your eyes, and the paths of those photons are not going to change just because you changed your velocity.   What you see depends entirely on where you are and which way you're facing, not on how fast you're going.

But second:  Your *interpretation* of what you see might change, leading you to **say** that certain photons are now coming from different angles than before.  To see exactly how this happens, see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/275220/use-of-angular-diameter-to-determine-distance-in-special-relativity/).